# Converting Oracle upsert to AzureSQL(T-SQL) prepared statement

Tags: t-sql, jdbc, azure-sql-database, prepared-statement, upsert

I want to migrate upsert queries from Oracle DB to AzureSQL. Below shows an Oracle prepared statement that takes values from dual and does an upsert operation on the DUMMY table.

```
MERGE INTO DUMMY a
USING (SELECT ? ID,
              ? NAME,
              ? SIZE from dual) b
ON (a.ID = b.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET a.ID = b.ID,
        a.NAME = b.NAME,
        a.SIZE = b.SIZE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(a.ID,
           a.NAME,
           a.SIZE)
    VALUES ( b.ID,
             b.NAME,
             b.SIZE)
```

I also asked for a migration from Oracle to Postgres earlier. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68843763/12328682) is the PostgreSQL version that I asked. I am looking for a way to convert into AzureSQL now.

Comment: No idea, I don't know Azure, but MERGE you wrote won't work as you can't UPDATE column referenced in the ON clause (ID in this case).

Comment: Oracle upserts are working correctly now on a live system. T-SQL version is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upsert for T-SQL.

```
MERGE dbo.table_name AS [Target]
USING (SELECT 1 AS Id, 'name' as t_name, 1 as size) AS [Source] 
   ON [Target].Id = [Source].Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET [Target].name = [Source].t_name, [Target].size = [Source].size
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (Id, name, size) VALUES ([Source].Id, [Source].t_name, [Source].size);
```

Use parameter value for preparing source table

```
DECLARE @id int = 1,
        @name varchar(10) = 'ABC',
        @size int = 5

MERGE dbo.table_name AS [Target]
USING (SELECT @id AS Id, @name as t_name, @size as size) AS [Source] 
   ON [Target].Id = [Source].Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET [Target].name = [Source].t_name, [Target].size = [Source].size
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (Id, name, size) VALUES ([Source].Id, [Source].t_name, [Source].size);
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=13d32c099991dc3001fe4a8cd0b3fc77

Comment: Can you tell the logic in the line 2? Why are we writing
"USING (SELECT 1 AS Id, 'name' as t_name, 1 as size) AS [Source]"? Values should be taken from a prepared statement. Do you know the character for that?

For example in oracle:"?" in postgres:"excluded"

Comment: I've prepared a dummy table as source table. You can use a database table instead of dummy table as source. I've followed the above example that's why I've preparing dummy table. If my answer helps you please mark it as accepted along with upvote so that any one pick that answer without any doubt.

Comment: Thanks, it helps and does the magic for database upsert query. The only thing is instead of giving custom values like "1 AS Id, 'name' as t_name...", how can we take those values as parameters? I will pass values using jdbc prepared-statement.

Comment: Please check this new query where dummy table has been prepared by using parameter.